# problems trying to convert c sharp code into java

Tags: java, c#

i'm try find most similar string in a array, and i found a code in c sharp that is this one

```
  public static int LevenshteinDistance(string s, string t)
    {
        int n = s.Length;
        int m = t.Length;
        int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return m;
        }
        if (m == 0)
        {
            return n;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            {
                int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;
                Console.WriteLine(cost);
                d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                    Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                    d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);


            }
        }
        return d[n, m];
    }
```

and i'm trying to convert it into java but i get 1 error this is my code in java

```
    public static int LevenshteinDistance(String s, String t)
       {
         int n = s.length();
        int m = t.length();
        int[][] d = new int[n + 1][ m + 1];
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return m;
        }
        if (m == 0)
        {
            return n;
        }



        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            {


            int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1])? 0 : 1;

                d[i][ j] = Math.min(
                    Math.min(d[i - 1][ j] + 1, d[i][ j - 1] + 1),
                    d[i - 1][ j - 1]+cost );
            }
        }
        return d[n] [m];
    }
```

i get the error  in this line of code
 int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;
the error that i have is  "Array is required,but string found" this is what i have in my main

```
         String []ray ={"food","drinks","stuffs"};
         String fa="drink";
        for (int i = 0; i < ray.length; i++)
        {

         System.out.print(LevenshteinDistance(fa, ray[i]));
        }
```

i would appreciate any help

Comment: You should use t.charAt(j-1) == s.charAt(i-1)   as to access characters (letters) in string You cannot access them directly via index (brackets []).

Comment: thanks u it works <3  i have another question what does mean the ? 0 : 1;

Comment: It is ternary operator (ternary = Three) - check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java). It means: (Condition)?(DoIfTrue):(DoIfFalse);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use t.charAt(j-1) == s.charAt(i-1)   as to access characters (letters) in string You cannot access them directly via index (brackets []).

```
int cost = (t.charAt(j - 1) == s.charAt(i - 1))? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: thanks u it works i have another question what does mean the  ? 0 : 1;

Comment: It is ternary operator (ternary = Three) - check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java). It means: (Condition)?(DoIfTrue):(DoIfFalse);

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the strings as arrays here with the [] array operator:

```
t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]
```

to get the nth char of a string, instead use .charAt(n)
so in this case change it to:

```
t.charAt(j - 1) == s.charAt(i - 1)
```

the same applies to the rest of the code.